# How to cancel the button to return to the previous app in the upper left corner of IOS

Tags: ios

I'm making a magic software. I have a function of secretly jumping from my app to other apps, but there is a headache. After each jump, the button to return to the previous app will be displayed in the upper left corner. Is there any way I can stop it (the target app is not the app I developed). Thank you very much

By the way ,I hope you can help me with Obj-C language. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: No, this is not possible.

Comment: I came up with an alternative. Before I jump, I modify my displayName to be empty, so that only an arrow will be displayed in the upper left corner of the target app, which will not attract attention. My question now is, can I use code to modify the displayName of the project

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.